# Ubuntu, Chrome - saved passwords disappeared. Failed to load entries from password store. Encryption service failure

Tags: google-chrome, password

Have reinstalled Ubuntu reusing the same `/home` partition for the nth time.
But this time, unlike others, the password manager on chrome refused to work properly.

The passwords are still in the google chrome password manager - I can see them on different machines. But on one machine, the one that I have just reinstalled I cannot see any password. And neither works saving new passwords - they are not saved anywhere. I get a prompt to save the password but after logging out I need to type them again.

How can I solve this issue.

Posting here as I believe this is an issue with password manager rather than Google Chrome itself.

From google chrome logs:

```
[6983:6983:1014/162114.233032:ERROR:password_sync_bridge.cc(439)] 
Passwords datatype error was encountered: Failed to load entries from 
password store. Encryption service failure.
```

And from syslog

```
Oct 14 15:49:34 ola google-chrome.desktop[13312]: 
[13304:13304:1014/154934.522560:ERROR:password_sync_bridge.cc(439)] 
Passwords datatype error was encountered: Failed to load entries from 
password store. Encryption service failure.
```

Answer (score 4):

[Augusto](https://askubuntu.com/users/209229/augusto)'s comment works for me on Ubuntu 18.04

1. Goto  "chrome://flags/" and enable the #clean-undecryptable-passwords
2. Wait for Chrome to restart
3. Goto "chrome://sync/"
4. Click "Trigger GetUpdates" to re-sync all data
5. Wait for a moment and you can use password autofill again

Comment: This worked for me!! Any idea why this happened ? I updated my system and bunch of other things so i imagine it has something to do with it but curious what happened.

Comment: Perhaps this option disappeared in Chrome 119?

Answer (score 2):

Password sync on Chrome produces several weird behaviours.

I figured out with [comment #20](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1251355#c20).

If this won't work for you, take a closer look at chrome://sync/ where you may find usefull info for your debug

In picture, right side "Type info > Passwords" running fine. Left side, debug tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have removed the Chrome account and added again.

Only works if clearing the bookmarks, history, passwords checkbox is checked.

[image]

Comment: I expect Sync  to work without login/logout

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue,

Checked that I have file under, which was not empty (it is the DB with passwords), created backup for it just in case.

[image]

Restarted my computer and worked fine again ...

Some times the most traditional solution 'Restart computer' works !